# Create tar on remote server and send it back over SSH

Tags: ssh, backup, tar

All the scripts I've seems to be pushing code from server to a backup server, I am trying to set the backup server to pull code from a live server.

I've managed it with the sql:

```
ssh -C user@111.11.111.111 mysqldump -u user --password=test example | gzip > Backups/SQL_Backups/example/example_`date +%d%b%Y`.sql.gz
```

And that **works perfectly**, but now I'm trying to `tar` a public folder and send it back, so far I've managed to ssh on and `tar` the correct folder, but how do I send it back?

```
ssh -C user@111.11.111.111 tar -c --bzip2 -f backup.tar /home/user/example.com/public/
```

I've tried doing this but it creates a blank archive

```
ssh -C user@111.11.111.111 tar -c --bzip2 -f backup.tar /home/user/example.com/public/ | Backups/File_Backups/example/example_public_`date +%d%b%Y`.tar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try with:

```
 ssh user@111.11.111.111 tar -c --bzip2 -f - /home/user/example.com/public/ > Backups/File_Backups/example/example_public_`date +%d%b%Y`.tar.bz2
```

Comment: That works great! I did try the > method but I didnt know you could put - as the file name as I was getting a blank archive, thanks!

Comment: Please also note that I removed -C in `ssh`, you do not want gzip compression for data compressed with bzip2.